# Dual of semidefinite program (SDP)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I want to derive the  dual of the following SDP

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\min_{\substack{W_{1} \in \mathbb{S}^{m}, W_{2} \in \mathbb{S}^{n}}} & \frac 12 \mbox{tr}(W_{1}) + \frac 12 \mbox{tr}(W_{2}) + \gamma \, \mbox{tr}(e^T e Z)\ \\
\text{subject to} & 
\begin{bmatrix}
W_{1} &  X \\
X^T & W_{2}
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
-Z_{ij}\leq Y_{ij} \leq Z_{ij}\\ e^T X e = mn\\ X_{ij}-Y_{ij}=0\\ X_{ij}\leq 1\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

I feel confused about the last term of the objective function and some constraints. Thank you.

Comment: Are $W_i$ the only variables? What is the dual you can come up with?

Comment: I think you probably intend to have $ee^T$ inside of that objective term instead of $ee^T$.